# SSMS 2012 CSV exports

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to prevent SSMS 2012 from adding the word 'NULL' to CSV exports?

Steps to reproduce behavior:

- Create a new query (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
- Select Query | Results To | Results to Grid (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
- Run query: `SELECT getdate() NOW, NULL DUMMY`; results in one row and two columns, the second column displays ‘NULL'
- Right click the results pane and choose Save Results As…; save the file as CSV
- Open the file with Notepad (view the ‘raw’ values)

Actual result:

```
NOW,DUMMY
2015-10-16 10:25:28.403,NULL
```

Desired result:

```
NOW,DUMMY
2015-10-16 10:25:28.403,
```

Is there a setting that will produce the desire result?  Do newer versions of SSMS work differently in this regard?

Comment: `SELECT getdate() NOW, '' DUMMY`? Just don't select NULL, select an empty string instead.

Comment: The query generates a null to *simulate' behavior in 'real' queries; I wanted to demonstrate how nulls are exports to CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `COALESCE(NullableColumn,'')` for any column you don't want to export with `NULL` values.

That `COALESCE` will output zero-length strings instead.

Most of the time, however, it is important to know the difference between a zero-length string and a `NULL` value in exported data.

You're sample query would become:

```
SELECT getdate() NOW, COALESCE(NULL,'') DUMMY;
```

Although, I'd really prefer to see it as:

```
SELECT [Now] = getdate()
    , Dummy = COALESCE(NULL,'');
```

Putting the column alias at the beginning of the line makes it easier to find columns referenced in the output when doing debugging work down the road.